# Data Normalization using Pytorch

Tags: image-processing, pytorch, normalization

I'm starting to work on the classification of images dataset, as many tutorials I followed; it starts by normalizing the data (train and test data)

My question is: if I want to normalize the data by **shifting** and **scaling** it with a factor of 0.5

What does this mean '**the factor of something x**'?

I know that it will be used within `.Normalize()`:

```
transform_train = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(),
])

transform_test = transforms.Compose([
    transforms.ToTensor(),
    transforms.Normalize(),
])
```

But I'm a little bit confused about the meaning shift and scale (maybe it's like resize?) by the factor of X

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Shifting and scaling refers to the color space. What you do is you subtract the mean (shifting to the mean of the pixel *values* of the whole dataset to 0) and divide by the standard deviation (scaling the pixel *values* to [0, 1].

It has nothing to do with modifying the size of the image or the like.

In numy you would do something like:

```
mean, std = np.mean(image), np.std(image)
image = image - mean
image = image / std
```

Note: You wouldn't want to normalize the data bz just 0.5 but by its mean and standard deviation.